# LINQ select data for a chart, order by month in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a chart in my web application written with ASP .NET Core which displays data from a database table.
The chart should display monthly data for the year (that will be 07.2020 to 07.2021) by month, but as you can see, the months in the chart are not in the correct order:[image]
I select data from database using LINQ, how can I display months in the chart in the correct order (jan -> feb -> mar etc.)? I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
var date = _azdb.kipKtg.Where(k => k.dtMonth.Value.Year.Equals(DateTime.Now.Year) ||
 k.dtMonth.Value.Year.Equals(DateTime.Now.Year - 1))
.Select(k => k.dtMonth)
.OrderBy(k => DateTime.Now.Month)
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

Comment: you are not ordering at all ... because you are ordering by constant value which is current month

Comment: also using distinct smelly ... very bad

Comment: @Selvin, can you please elaborate on why distinct use here is incorrect?

Comment: Could you elaborate **why you need it ?** ... I've seen many DISTINCT usage almost all of them were not necessary and error prone (fx distinct instead of group by or distinct because someone join table whith one to many instead of `EXISTS`)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.OrderBy(k => DateTime.Now.Month)` you should try `.OrderBy(k => k.Month)`.

Also note that you have to do `Distinct` before calling `OrderBy` for not messing the order.

Comment: Sure forgot to note, that you have to use `Distinct` before `OrderBy`, just updated the answer